# Is there any possible way to run Android apps on Windows Subsystem for Android by Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, windows-11

It would be great if we can debug Android apps on Windows Subsystem for Android.

Comment: What do you mean by Windows Subsystem?

Comment: https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2021/10/20/introducing-android-apps-on-windows-11-to-windows-insiders/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Of course that is possible, it works similar to any external device.

First enable Developer mode in Windows Subsystem for Android Settings application.
[Windows Subsystem for Android settings application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVaIF.png)

[image: pic]

Then, connect ADB either like `adb.exe connect 127.0.0.1:58526` or `adb.exe connect <that ip assigned to your WSA device>` once connect, just proceed as usual.

Go to Run -> Select Device
[Android Studio select device menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8fTK.png)

[image: pic2]

If ADB had connected correctly, it will be listed there as `Microsoft Corporation Subsystem for Android(TM)`
[List of devices available to connect to in Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/as7mb.png)

[image: pic3]

And that's it, it will be available as target the external device to debug with.
[Android Studio and WSA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9ZDl.png)

[image: pic4]

Now you can compile and Debug (Shift+F9) from Android Studio and Windows Subsystem for Android launching it and pausing accordingly (breakpoints, exceptions, etc.)
[Debugging APK from Android Studio with WSA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yEbr.png)

[image: pic5]

[Debugging APK from Android Studio with WSA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5QEp.png)

[image: pic6]

If you want to tweak more the debugging settings, you can launching its View in WSA from that Settings application.
[WSA more debugging settings from within the Android instance itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwcOq.png)

[image: pic7]

Comment: Do you know where it is now (the IP and port)? It's not there anymore