# Android Studio automatically connect to Windows Subsystem for Android

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, windows-11

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69685615/10557332), it's already possible to connect Android Studio to WSA. But, after you restart Android Studio, it disconnects the Android Debug Bridge and you need to run `adb connect <WSA instance IP>` again.

Is there a way to automatically tell the ADB to connect to WSA when you start up Android Studio, or simply keep it connected?

Comment: Is it possible that your Windows has multiple installations of adb (search for `adb.exe`)? If you switch adb the adb server can be restarted which could result in a reset of all connected endpoints.

Comment: Not to my knowledge. I ran a file search to verify, but that also did not return any additional adb installs. 
However, I did notice while I ran the search that Android Studio did disconnect from my WSA instance even when I didn't close it.

Comment: Check Taskmanager for adb.exe processes and note their PID. Next time it had disconnected check if the PID has changed. Lately adb seems to be ab bit unstable. If ADB server crashes silently it will be automatically restarted on use.